# Air drying acetic acid solution

Tags: acid-base

So I'm cleaning up a lot of my stuff to have more space and I have 2 jugs of grocery bought white vinegar jugs (5% acetic acid). Naturally to make it more compact, I'm trying to concentrate it. I was wondering if leaving the vinegar out in a warm place to let the water evaporate will be effective.

I know that acetic acid solutions form azeotropes at wide ranges, so I might actually be evaporating the acetic acid along with it.

So would it work?

Comment: In short, no. You'll evaporate everything pretty soon.